# how to convert Node and Arc sets representation to an adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

What am I doing wrong?

```
N=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
A=[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]

for i in range (len(N)):
    for j in range (len(N)):
        my_list1 = [i[0] for i in A]
        my_list2 = [i[1] for i in A]
        print my_list1
        print my_list2
```

I am not getting this output instead im getting [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
repeated multiply times

```
ADJ=[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], \
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: As far as *repeated multiple times* is concerned , that is due to the use of print statement in nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach this requires building an empty adjacency matrix first, then populating it with a single pass through `A`. Here's a simple example that ignores the contents of `N`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def show(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print row
    print

N = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
A = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]

adj_target = [
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
show(adj_target)


size = len(N)
adj = [[0]*size for _ in range(size)]
#show(adj)

for u,v in A:
    adj[u-1][v-1] += 1

show(adj)

print adj == adj_target
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

True
```